# Are there some valid HTML entities without the semicolon?

Tags: html, html-entities

Looking at this official [entities.json](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/entities.json) file, some of the entities are defined without an ending semicolon.

For example:

```
"&Acirc": { "codepoints": [194], "characters": "\u00C2" },
"&Acirc;": { "codepoints": [194], "characters": "\u00C2" },
```

Where is that documented in HTML5? Or is that a browser *thing¹*?

¹ *thing* as in *extension* for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named HTML entities without a semicolon **are not valid**, per the HTML spec, but browsers are required to support some of them anyway. (This spec pattern - where something is officially illegal for you to do as a HTML author, but still has a single unambiguously specified behaviour that browsers must implement - is used a lot in the HTML spec.)

There are a few pertinent sections in the spec:

- [§13.1.4 Character references](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#character-references)

  Pertinent quote:

  > ##### Named character references
  >
  > The ampersand must be followed by one of the names given in the [named character references](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-character-references) section, using the same case. The name must be one that is terminated by a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;).
- [§13.2 Parsing HTML Documents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing), especially [13.2.5.73 Named character reference state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-character-reference-state) (if you really want to pick through the horrible hard-to-read implementation details of the parsing algorithm).
- The non-normative [**§1.11.2 Syntax errors**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#syntax-errors), which contains some explanation on why the spec makes references without semicolons errors (though I don't personally find it hugely compelling):

  > ##### Errors involving fragile syntax constructs
  >
  > There are syntax constructs that, for historical reasons, are relatively fragile. To help reduce the number of users who accidentally run into such problems, they are made non-conforming.
  >
  > ###### Example
  >
  > For example, the parsing of certain named character references in attributes happens even with the closing semicolon being omitted. It is safe to include an ampersand followed by letters that do not form a named character reference, but if the letters are changed to a string that does form a named character reference, they will be interpreted as that character instead.
  >
  > In this fragment, the attribute's value is `"?bill&ted"`:
  >
  > ```
  > <a href="?bill&ted">Bill and Ted</a>
  > ```
  >
  > In the following fragment, however, the attribute's value is actually `"?art©"`, not the intended `"?art&copy"`, because even without the final semicolon, `"&copy"` is handled the same as `"&copy;"` and thus gets interpreted as `"©"`:
  >
  > ```
  > <a href="?art&copy">Art and Copy</a>
  > ```
  >
  > To avoid this problem, all named character references are required to end with a semicolon, and uses of named character references without a semicolon are flagged as errors.
  >
  > Thus, the correct way to express the above cases is as follows:
  >
  > ```
  > <a href="?bill&ted">Bill and Ted</a> <!-- &ted is ok, since it's not a named character reference -->
  > <a href="?art&amp;copy">Art and Copy</a> <!-- the & has to be escaped, since &copy is a named character reference -->
  > ```

As a final bit of corroboration that entities like `&Acirc` are invalid but work anyway, we can use this test document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>Test page</title>
  <div>&Acirc</div>
</html>
```

Open it in Chrome, and it works and shows us an A with a circumflex accent:

[image: screenshot]

But paste it into the [Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) ([endorsed by WhatWG](https://whatwg.org/validator/)), and we get an error stating *"Named character reference was not terminated by a semicolon."*:

[image: screenshot]

i.e. it works, but it's invalid.

Answer (score 3):

HTML named character list is defined at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html and yes, some of these don't have a trailing `;` e.g `&not`

```html
&not
```

Comment: This is only half the story. Named characters without trailing semicolons are indeed included in the list, but other parts of the spec make clear that it's illegal to use them. This unintuitive state of affairs exists because the spec tries to unambiguously specify browser behaviour even for some illegal syntax (such as the use of these semicolon-less character references). The list of named character references includes all the ones *browsers* must support, but the ones without semicolons are officially forbidden for HTML authors to use, despite browsers supporting them.

Comment: @MarkAmery yes that's just [conformance requirements vs implementation.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/introduction.html#conformance-requirements-for-authors) Just like you can have the same id on multiple elements. Not sure what that pragmatically change regarding this question though. The entities exist, that they make the doc non conforming doesn't change a dime.

Answer (score 1):

I made a program in python to get some numbers, and I found out that:

In the 2231 total entities, there are **4.75%** or **106 valid entities without a semi-colon at end**

All those entities:

```html
&AElig, &AMP, &Aacute, &Acirc, &Agrave, &Aring, &Atilde, &Auml, &COPY, &Ccedil, &ETH, &Eacute, &Ecirc, &Egrave, &Euml, &GT, &Iacute, &Icirc, &Igrave, &Iuml, &LT, &Ntilde, &Oacute, &Ocirc, &Ograve, &Oslash, &Otilde, &Ouml, &QUOT, &REG, &THORN, &Uacute, &Ucirc, &Ugrave, &Uuml, &Yacute, &aacute, &acirc, &acute, &aelig, &agrave, &amp, &aring, &atilde, &auml, &brvbar, &ccedil, &cedil, &cent, &copy, &curren, &deg, &divide, &eacute, &ecirc, &egrave, &eth, &euml, &frac12, &frac14, &frac34, &gt, &iacute, &icirc, &iexcl, &igrave, &iquest, &iuml, &laquo, &lt, &macr, &micro, &middot, &nbsp, &not, &ntilde, &oacute, &ocirc, &ograve, &ordf, &ordm, &oslash, &otilde, &ouml, &para, &plusmn, &pound, &quot, &raquo, &reg, &sect, &shy, &sup1, &sup2, &sup3, &szlig, &thorn, &times, &uacute, &ucirc, &ugrave, &uml, &uuml, &yacute, &yen, &yuml
```